# При оформлении заказа как записывать незарегистрированного клиента

Tags: php, mysql, crm, order

При оформлении заказа как записывать незарегистрированного клиента. То есть, к примеру, клиент совершил покупку с помощью наличными, как записывать его в системе.Если это делает зарегистрированный покупатель, у него сохраняется id допустим. А с незарегистрированным непонятно.

Comment: Точно так же, но без `id`. Предположу, что при заказе пользователь указывает личные данные, по которым вы можете его идентифицировать. А если используется эквайринг, то можно много информации получить из него

Comment: Можно проводить не явную регистрацию, так же можно выдавать временную регистрацию, основываясь на куках. Оба варианта позволят пользователю детектить прогресс выполнения заказа. При пост регистрации, купленный ранее товар будет в истории юзера.

Comment: А если допустим такая ситуация. Покупатель оплатил наличными, и нет эквайринга. То есть данных об этом покупателе никаких не имеем. Как тогда система будет регистрировать этого человека в системе?